# xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError on parsing XML

Tags: python, xml, httpwebrequest, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have been trying to retrieve information through HTTP queries, as an example

http://www.opencellid.org/cell/get?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&mnc=1&mcc=228&lac=101&cellid=7283

returns me a response in XML format, like

```
<rsp stat="ok">
<cell nbSamples="1" mnc="1" lac="101" lat="46.52079" lon="6.56676" cellId="7283" mcc="228" range="6000"/>
</rsp>
```

I have tried using the `response` and `urllib` modules to open the URL, and then parse using  `elementtree.ElementTree`.

Code snippet:

```
url = 'http://www.opencellid.org/cell/get?key=xxxxxxxxxx&mnc=1&mcc=228&lac=101&cellid=7283 '
rss = parse(requests.get(url = url)).getroot()
pprint(rss)
```

I however get the following error:

```
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: junk after document element: line 5, column 0
```

Just printing the response yields the HTML success code. Some help please!

Comment: Where does the requests module(object?) come from? Can you expand the code snippet to also specify the modules you're importing?

Comment: import requests,

from pprint import pprint,

from elementtree.ElementTree import parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call content on the response object. That's how you get the actual xml.

```
content = requests.get(url = url).content
rss = parse(content).getroot()
```

Comment: Thanks.
Now i can at least print the content, however the parser has other problems :| 
But i think i can handle this soon.

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/elementtree/ElementTree.py", line 859, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/elementtree/ElementTree.py", line 576, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: It looks like parse is expecting a file rather than a string. You should either look for a different method or do something like: import StringIO; rss = parse(StringIO.StringIO(content)).getroot()

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Works perfectly on using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead of elementtree

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd advise would be to save a text file only with the content of the xml:

```
 <rsp stat="ok">
    <cell nbSamples="1" mnc="1" lac="101" lat="46.52079" lon="6.56676" cellId="7283" mcc="228" range="6000"/>
 </rsp>
```

just make sure there are no trailing characters at the end. Then check it the parsing works.
If it does, then you know its a communication problem, and then have to figure how to 'clean' up what you are receiving.

Good luck!

Comment: How exactly can I do that? This _"pprint(requests.get(url = url))"_ prints the HTML response code.